# Update whole data series for the graph

Tags: highcharts

What I wanna do: I have a basic line chart which is initialy load with an array of data (series: [...]) which creates me lets say x lines. I will also render x checkboxes above the chart. On click on one of the checkboxes the corresponding line should disappear or appear. Therefor I am listening to the click event and then I want to add or remove a line.

The problem: I can not figure out how to replace the whole series with a new one. What I have found is the setData() method, but that only works on an item of the data array. I also found the methods addSeries() which will add an item. And remove() which will remove a specific item. The problem is, I dont know which item is which. What I would like is to hide a line or show them, but have the full x lines in the data series all the time. I think.

I also found the method update() which will let me pass a new configuration object to the chart, but its not working if i pass the option 'series: newData (array)'.

I am either looking for an option to pass the full data array at the beginning and then hide or show a line, or, to overwrite the full series data at any given them with a new array.

Hopefully thats understandable and someone can point out what I am missing! Thanks!

Comment: If your requirement is is to hide and display one line on click , that is provided by highcharts out of the box. 
You have `legend` to enable and disable lines in a chart.
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.enabled. Will this solves your purpose ?

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer! unfortunately, what you have pointed out, would only enable and disable the legend. not the series itself. but I found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I would load the whole data array in the beginning and show or hide certain series for the initial display with the option visible:false.

On click of the checkboxes I need to find the right series and then there are the methods show() and hide() to manipulate that visible property on runtime.

```
chart.series[myIndex].show();
chart.series[myIndex].hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setVisible` method for series and bind checkboxes with the series:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById('checkboxes').children;

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            chart.series[i].setVisible(this.checked);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ur31g4j5/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible